# How many sets below are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$S_1=\{(a,a+b,a+b+c)\mid a,b,c\in \mathbb R\}\\
S_2=\{(1,a+b,a+b+c)\mid a,b,c\in \mathbb R\}\\
S_3=\left\{(a,b,c)\mid \Bigg|\begin{matrix}a&0&1\\0&a&c\\0&0&b\\\end{matrix}\Bigg|=0\right\}\\
S_4=\left\{(a,b,c)\mid \Bigg|\begin{matrix}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\a&b&c\\\end{matrix}\Bigg|=0\right\}\\$$
I know that $S_1$ is a subspace $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $S_2$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

But I'm not sure how to determine if $S_3$ and $S_4$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ or not, need some help here thanks!

Comment: Work out the determinants. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

**hint**
For $S_3$.

The determinant is $$a^2b$$

$$V_1=(0,1,1)\in S_3$$

$$V_2=(1,0,1)\in S_3$$

What about $V_1+V_2$.

Answer (score 1):

$S_3$ is not a subspace because the determinant condition implies $a^2b=0$

$S_4$ is a subspace  because the determinant condition implies $a=c$